# Twitter API and operator

Tags: twitter

I want to make a simple Twitter API get using JSON.  The idea is to get only the posts from a known corporation (say BigCorporation) sent to the main corporation (@BigCorporation).  The idea is to just get the main annoncements and filter out anytime the BigCoporation answer a question from a follower (i.e. BigCoporation tweets: @someguy we are anwering your question)

So Tweets from:BigCoporation with the @BigCorporation

I came up with this API get but I seem to get both @BigCorporation or from:BigCorporation tweets.  I want only the Tweets that are @BigCorp AND from:BigCorp

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@BigCorporation&q=from:BigCorporation&result_type=mixed

Comment: Are you sure the BigCorp is posting tweets addressed to itself so it can be both: @BigCorp AND from:BigCorp ?

Answer (score 1):

Your search query is malformed.

It should be:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@edent%20from:edent&result_type=mixed
```

That will show you all the tweets I have sent which contains the string "@edent"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this URL :
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=BigCorporation&exclude_replies=true

The REST method `GET https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json` returns the most recent tweets (20 by default) of a user whose username (here BigCorporation) is in the parameter `screen_name`. When set to true (or t or 1), the `exclude_replies` parameter excludes the tweets that you want to avoid ("@someguy we are anwering your question").

You can visit [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) on the Twitter API website for further details.